# With Capybara, how do I switch to the new window when i have already switched to the window?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

I need to call another helper inside my helper (which one opens in new window) and open and switch to another window, but when i'm trying to do this - i'm receiving this error:

```
Capybara::ScopeError:
   `switch_to_window` is not supposed to be invoked from `within`'s, `within_frame`'s' or `within_window`'s' block.
```

Is there a way to open and switch to another window?

[EDIT1]

```
def create_ticket(kind, products = [])
  visit('inventory/parcels/')
  products.each do |product|
    if product[:serialized]
      serialized = find_device(product[:status], product[:id])
```

So here is the find_device helper:

```
def find_device(status_id, product_id)
  within_window open_new_window do
  visit('inventory/items?per=25)
```

Comment: It would help if you posted some of the offending code.

Comment: @mmichael i added code which causes error. thanks in advance

Comment: does `within_window(switch_to_window(windows.last)) do YOUR CODE end` work for you?

Comment: Is `create_ticket` called inside another `within_window` block?  It would really help if you posted enough code that we could actually tell what was happening.

Comment: no, i'm receiving 'no such session' error (think its because drive doesnn't opens new window and trying to switch to it

Comment: @twttr Was that "no" response to my question or the one asked by fabersky ?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole that was response to fabersky's question.
yes, create_ticket called inside another within_window, so why i'm receiving such error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way (currently) to switch to another window from inside `within_window` (without dropping to driver specific methods).  You could switch to just using `switch_to_window` everywhere rather than `within_window` but then you'd have to very carefully manually manage the scope stack, and switching back to original windows.  A better approach would probably be to restructure your test so you don't need to leap between multiple windows simultaneously.

That being said, the restriction is actually unnecessary in Capybara nowadays and will probably be relaxed in the next release - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/1882